# add line in cmake to edit Makefile definition

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, suppress-warnings

In my cmake file, I am specifying `add_definitions ( -DBOOST_SIGNALS_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING )`. However, I am still seeing the warning `warning: #warning "Boost.Signals is no longer being maintained and is now deprecated. Please switch to Boost.Signals2. To disable this warning message, define BOOST_SIGNALS_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING." [-Wcpp]`. How do I properly define `BOOST_SIGNALS_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING`?

**edit**

This cmake file generates a make file. I get the error during the execution of the Makefile. I can't edit the CMakeLists.txt file. Is it possible to set this flag to be on for the generated Makefile using a cmake file?

Comment: That should work.  Are you sure you've not got a typo?  If not, you'll need to at least show us your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: This cmake file generates a make file. I get the error during the execution of the `Makefile`. I can't edit the CMakeLists.txt file. Is it possible to set this flag to be on for the generated `Makefile` using a cmake file?

Comment: That's a bit confusing!  Anyway, depending on how the CMakeLists.txt is written, you might get away with running CMake like this: `cmake . -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-DBOOST_SIGNALS_NO_DEPRECATION_WARNING`.  That's not as good an option though as setting the definition in the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Something I can stick in the cmake file would of course be ideal, but it looks like it simply cannot be done in this situation